# JSP got http error while refreshing the page

Tags: java, html, jsp, jdbc

I went through a basic tutorial about JSP and JDBC and wrote some java code in eclipse and try deploying using JSP

Here is the JSP code, basically it list all the rows (name and price) in the database and you can submit name and price by pressing the button (not implemented yet) :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
import ="edu.neu.cs5200.s3.onlineide.applications.*, java.util.*"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Applications</h1>
<%
  applicationsDAO dao = new applicationsDAO();
  String action=request.getParameter("action");
  String name=request.getParameter("name");
  String price=request.getParameter("price");
  String id=request.getParameter("id");

if("create".equals(action)){
      double priceD=Double.parseDouble(price);
      Application app=new Application(name, priceD);
      dao.create(app);
}

   List<Application> applications=dao.selectAll();
%>
<form action="application.jsp">

<table class="table">
    <tr>
         <td><input name="name" class="form-control"/></td>
         <td><input name="price" class="form-control"/></td>
         <td>
           <button class="btn" name="action" value="create">
              Add
           </button>
         </td>

         <td></td>

    </tr>
<%  for (Application app: applications){
%>      <tr>
           <td><%=app.getName() %></td>
           <td><%=app.getPrice()%></td>
        </tr>
<% 
  } 
%>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It originally looks like this:
[image]

However, when I enter "Checkers" and "599" press the "add" button, it looks like this:
[image]

Based on the tutorial, since I have not implemented the button yet, it should looks like the original page with the only change that the url changes to http://localhost:8080/OnlineIDE/application.jsp?name=Checkers&price=5.99&action=create when I enter "Checkers" and "5.99" but I got a http error. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original was for `applications.jsp`, but later your link is to `application.jsp`.  You forgot the s.